# Installation problem of Lomboz in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I was told that Lomboz might be handy for eclipse and now its turn to get stuck installing this. I have extracted this as suggested in plugins directory of eclipse. But eclipse is not recognizing Lomboz (in the customize perspective and select shortcuts, select new and I don't see Lomboz yet). 
Anyone could help? Thank you very much.

Cheers
A

Answer (score 0):

The [latests builds from Lomboz](http://forge.ow2.org/project/showfiles.php?group_id=97) are from 2007, for Eclipse3.3, so it may suffer from problems with more recent Eclipse (3.5, 3.6).
Although an [update was announced for June 2009](http://forge.ow2.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=6606&forum_id=360), it never came.